# Message not defined + The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I was trying to make a code where the bot sends another reply when the bot is used more than one time but for some reson it does not work

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('Ich teste was'),

    
    async execute(interaction) {
        
       
        const msg = await interaction.reply({
            content: "Am Testen",
            
        })
        const {reply} = message ?? interaction;
const userId = message.author.id ?? message.member.id ?? interaction.member.id ?? interaction.author.id;
const uses = await db.get(`uses_test_${userId}`) + 1;
await db.set(`uses_test_${userId}`, uses);
if (uses > 1) {
    return reply("Du testest nun etwas zum 2x")
    }}

}
```

Bot is sending a different reply (not random) when using the command a second time (or more)

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please provide examples of intended output.

Comment: When I do the command the first time, the console already logs "ReferenceError: message is not defined" but still sends the first reply like intendet, when I send it the second time the bot crashes with the error "Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred."

Comment: There seems to already be a problem on the first attempt -- maybe if you fixed that the problem on the second attempt would go away as well?

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: The `message` variable was never declared
Issue 2: You have two reply functions

Here's how to fix:

1. Change `msg` to just `interaction.reply()` (Shorten)
2. Remove `{reply}` (Don't need this)
3. Shorten `userId` (Issue 1)
4. Use `interaction.channel.send()` instead of `reply()` (Issue 2)

Example code:

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    interaction.reply("Am Testen");
    const userId = interaction.user.id;
    const uses = await db.get(`uses_test_${userId}`) + 1;
    await db.set(`uses_test_${userId}`, uses);
    if (uses > 1) {
        return interaction.channel.send("Du testest nun etwas zum 2x");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks your help, everything seems to work again, except when I try to use it a second time, the new error is "ReferenceError: db is not defined"

Comment: @Senpai you need to define db in your code since you use db in your question